# Making a div extend to the bottom of a page minus a set amount

Tags: php, html

I have tried to make a page extend to the bottom of a page however it only extends to about half of the page. I have the height of the main-bg div to 100% but it does not extend this far. How can I get it to go 100% of the page?

I have a main-bg div to hold the text backdrop, and a fade in and out for it on both the top and bottom but the bottom one does not reach the bottom of the page. To show you, what I have done looks like [Page](http://www.skittles-server.net/index-1.php) but i would like the fade half way through to be at the bottom of a page.

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Please provide your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

What about using:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

This would put it on the bottom of the page. Just change the bottom value to something greater than 0px to set that amount you are needing.

Comment: This moves the div to the bottom of the page, but does not change the height. I believe he wants a div with height 100%.